# relations between differential, partial derivative, directional derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I am a bit lost. Could you explain me relations between differential, partial derivative,
directional derivative? I mean that I need some theorem and proofs that for example if differential exists then partial derivative exists.
I will be so grateful

Comment: If a function is differentiable, then it's partials exist. The converse is not true. For a discussion of the latter, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596332/confused-about-differentiability-continuity-partial-derivative-existence.

Comment: Ok, thank you but what about directional derivative?

Comment: I added a response to that below. In summary, you can kind of say that, if $f$ is "nice" (differentiable), then we can use the partials to express the differential, and the directional derivatives. Note that the directional derivatives are generalizations of the partials, and otherwise, could be more difficult to calculate. The differential (in it's more formal definition, acting more like the total derivative?) in a sense is an object that implicitly contains information about the directional derivatives, and of course the partials.

Answer (score 1):

We define the directional derivative of $f$ at $(a,b)$, in the direction ${\bf v}=(v_x,v_y)$ as

$$f_{\bf v}(a,b) 
= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(a+hv_x,b+hv_y)-f(a,b)}{h},$$

provided the limit exists.

However, if the function is "nice", that is, differentiable at $(a,b)$, then we can express the directional derivative in terms of the partial derivatives,

$$f_{\bf v}(a,b) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(a,b)} v_x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(a,b)} v_y.$$

(This is better, as now you can calculate for any vector quickly, and the partials are likely easy to calculate.)

Notice the resemblance with the expression for the differential you may have seen,

$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy.$$

This expression too makes little sense unless $f$ is differentiable (at the point in question).