# are the partial derivatives must be continuous in the chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $g(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ and suppose that $g'(t)$ exist in $t=t_0$. By the chain rule, if the partial derivatives of a function $f(x,y)$ are continuous in an open neighborhood of $g(t_0)=P$, then 
$$
(f\circ g)'(t_0)=f_x(P)x'(t_0)+f_y(P)y'(t_0).
$$
Are the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ must be continuous in $P$ or there exist a version of the chain rule with weaker conditions?

Comment: This has been answered here.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596332/confused-about-differentiability-continuity-partial-derivative-existence

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n},\ B\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$ open sets and let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^{m},\ g:B\to\mathbb{R^{l}}$ be functions such that:

1. $f$ is differentiable at $a\in A$
2. $g$ is differentiable at $f(a)$
3. $f(A)\subseteq B$

Then, $g_{o}f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $(g_{o}f)'(a)=g'(f(a))f'(a)$.

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for. The OP wanted to know if $f$ differentiable implies that its partials are continuous.

Comment: are you sure? my english isnt good but: "Are the partial derivatives $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ must be continuous in $P$ or there exist a version of the chain rule with weaker conditions?"
Since continuous partial drivatives implies differentiability, the theorem i wrote is stronger

Comment: But differentiability does not implies that the partial derivatives are  continuous...

Comment: read carefully!