# Conditions at which relationship directional derivative and gradient holds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I saw somewhere a formula that states that the gradient (definition in 2 dimensions)

$$ \nabla f(x,y) =\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) $$

can be related to the directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector $\hat{u}$ as

$$ \nabla f(x,y) \cdot \hat{u}$$

However, it seems to me that this in certain cases does not hold.

Take for instance the function

$$ f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin\left(2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right) $$

which has the following contour and 3D plots:

[image][image]

If $x=0$ or $y=0$,

$$\sin\left(2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right) = 0 $$

So that $f$ is 0 on the x and y axis. Then if I'm not mistaken at the origin

$$ \nabla f(0,0) =\left(0, 0\right) $$

If $|x|=|y|$,

$$ \left|\sin\left(2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)\right| = 1 $$

It seems than that the slope in the direction of the unit vectors $(\pm 1, \pm1)$ should be 1. However, with the previous gradient

$$ \nabla f(x,y) \cdot \hat{u} = \vec{0}$$

Under what conditions then can this formula be used?

Comment: The function itself is not defined at $(0, 0)$, so doing something like $\nabla f(0, 0)$ is problematic

Comment: Oh right, because of the $\frac{y}{x}$. Though the limit from most directions would put it at 0 no? Then the condition that I'm looking for is that $f(x,y)$ is defined?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable then the formula holds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#For_differentiable_functions

Comment: @caverac: You can extend the function continuously by letting $f(0,0)=0$, so that in itself is not so problematic. But since (the extended) $f$ isn't differentiable at the origin, it doesn't make much sense to talk about the gradient $\nabla f(0,0)$ (even though $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ exist separately).

Comment: @HansLundmark Would you mind explaining why the function is not differentiable, even with the modification so that $(0,0)$ is part of the domain? Since the function limited to $x=0$ or $y=0$ would seem differentiable and their partial derivatives exist.

Comment: OK. First a correction: the original expression for $f(x,y)$ only makes sense when $x \neq 0$ (since we need to avoid division by zero in the innermost expresssion $y/x$), so I should have said “by letting $f(0,y)=0$ for all $y$” rather than just “by letting $f(0,0)=0”.

Comment: With that definition, $f$ is zero along both the coordinate axes, so both partials $f_x$ and $f_y$ are zero at the origin. But it's clear from the picture that the plane $z=f_x(0,0) \, x + f_y(0,0) \, y = 0x+0y$ isn't at all tangent to the graph $z=f(x,y)$ at the origin, which is what differentiability means. For example, if you go along the line $(x,y)=(t,t)$ then (as you already noticed yourself), the slope of the graph isn't zero.

Comment: Note that “differentiable” is a much stronger condition than “the partial derivatives exists”, since it involves the values of the function in a whole neighbourhood of the point, not just in the $x$ and $y$ directions.

Comment: See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596332/confused-about-differentiability-continuity-partial-derivative-existence).

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks, that's quite clear then. There not really being a tangent plane that approximates the function I think is the most clear way to see it for me.